# C++ variable_name.attribute = x

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dictionary, vector

I have seen [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgxNB.jpg), but I can't find what he's doing. I am in particular interested to `computers[I].name = 'ever'`: can you have a variable_name.attribute in c++? for example student.grade = 6, student.name = "Tedd" and so on?

Comment: This seems to be javascript or similar language, C++ does not support strings using single quotes, or the let keyword.

Comment: `let` isn't C++ either. But `foo.bar = 4;` is perfectly credible C++ syntax.

Comment: This looks normal and is explained in any C++ book out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not:

```
#include <string>

struct Computer {
  std::string name;
};

int main() {
  Computer computers[100];

  for (auto& cp : computers) {
    cp.name = "ever";
  }
}
```

---

Here is the student example you're interested in:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Student {
  std::string name;
  double grade;
};

int main() {
  Student students[3];
  students[0].name = "s1";
  students[0].grade = 95.7;

  students[1].name = "s2";
  students[1].grade = 96.6;

  students[2].name = "s3";
  students[2].grade = 77.4;

  for (Student const& s : students) {
    std::cout << s.name << " : " << s.grade << '\n';
  }
}
```

Hover to execute

> s1 : 95.7
>  s2 : 96.6
>  s3 : 77.4